# DataTables: Requested unknown parameter 'case' for row 1

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables. Currently this works when I do this:

```
{ "data": "case" }
```

But when I do this:

```
{ 
    "data": "case", 
    "render": function(data){
        if (data == "true"){
            return "<i class='fa fa-check-square-o'></i>";
        }
    }
}
```

it gives me pop-up error saying:

> Datatables warning: table id=peacecard -
>       Requested unknown parameter 'case' for row 1.
>       For more information about this error, please
>       see http://datatables.net/tn/4

After closing the pop-ups, the data is rendered correctly, but can't get rid of the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to always return value in [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) function despite your condition.

```js
{ 
    "data": "case", 
    "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
        if (data == "true"){
            data = "<i class='fa fa-check-square-o'></i>";
        } else {
            data = "";
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: WORKED WORKED WORKED! Thanks a lot!